# Audio Tag Doesn't Work in IE9

Tags: html, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I cannot for the life of me get the audio tag to work in IE9. Here is my code, what exactly am I doing wrong? I made sure my tags were all in order and I put an exception in to force IE9 to use HTML5. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CD Cover Animation</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animCD.js?rev=new"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Show Audio when button is clicked -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAudio()
        {
            document.getElementById('audioInterview').style.visibility='visible';
        }
    </script>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    </head>
    <body>

    <video autoplay="autoplay" id="videoBackground" width="1280" height="720" preload="auto" ontimeupdate="animCD_onprogress();">
        <source id="colorVid_mp4" type="video/mp4" src="img/luther-2.mp4">
        <source id="colorVid_ogg" type="video/ogg" src="img/luther-2.ogg">
    </video>


        <audio id="audioInterview" preload='auto' controls style="visibility:hidden"
            <source src="audio/interview.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>


    <!-- <div class="buttonSkip" onclick="alert('Clicked Skip');"></div> -->



    <p><a class="ex2" href="http://www.lrltv.org/muslims-nuclear.html">[ skip intro]</a></p>

    <div id="buttonPlacement" class="buttonPlacement">
        <div onclick="showAudio();" class="btnDonate"></div>
        <div onclick="alert('Clicked Buy');" class="btnBuy"></div>
    </div>
            <!-- Add more buttons here -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about closing the `audio` tag?

Comment: You aren't closing that audio tag and it looks like it would be better to set preload="auto" rather than preload='auto' for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say, you need to close the audio tag. But that they don't mean the `</audio>` but the `>` at the end of the line. It should look like this:

```
<audio id="audioInterview" preload="auto" controls="controls" style="visibility:hidden">
        <source src="audio/interview.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I also use the controls="controls".

If you don't need to show the audio control, you also do this in pure JavaScript.

```
var audioInterview = new Audio('audio/interview.mp3');
audioInterview.play();
```

And then remove the HTML audio tag.